Android Studio Native C++ proj for Meta Quest 3 using Oculus Mobile SDK get the accelerometer data with all zeros
I'm trying to use Android Studio's Native C++ proj to build a app in Meta Quest 3 to collect headset's accelerometer's x,y,z data, however, my code works properly, But in logcat, the Accelerometer's x, y and z data are always zeros no matter how I move the headset of meta quest 3.
I use the latest Oculus Mobile SDK's VrApi.h's function:
    const double predictedDisplayTime = vrapi_GetPredictedDisplayTime(mobile, 0);
    const ovrTracking2 tracking = vrapi_GetPredictedTracking2(mobile, predictedDisplayTime);
    float accX = tracking.HeadPose.LinearAcceleration.x;
    float accY = tracking.HeadPose.LinearAcceleration.y;
    float accZ = tracking.HeadPose.LinearAcceleration.z;

I also try to get velocity, orientation, however, both are also 0s. Below is my C++ code.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for usleep
#include "include/VrApi.h"
#include "include/VrApi_Helpers.h"
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <android/native_window.h>
#include <android/native_window_jni.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_oculusdemo_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    ovrJava java;
    java.Vm = nullptr;
    java.Env = env;
    java.ActivityObject = obj;
    env->GetJavaVM(&java.Vm);

    jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID getSurfaceMethod = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "getSurface", "()Landroid/view/Surface;");
    jobject surface = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, getSurfaceMethod);
    ANativeWindow *window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);

    if (!window) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "NativeWindow", "Failed to get ANativeWindow");
        return env->NewStringUTF("Failed to get ANativeWindow");
    }

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLint configAttribs[] = { EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, EGL_NONE };
    eglChooseConfig(display, configAttribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

    EGLint contextAttribs[] = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE };
    EGLContext context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttribs);

    ovrInitParms initParms = vrapi_DefaultInitParms(&java);
    if (vrapi_Initialize(&initParms) != VRAPI_INITIALIZE_SUCCESS) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "VrApi", "Failed to initialize VrApi");
        ANativeWindow_release(window);
        eglDestroyContext(display, context);
        eglTerminate(display);
        return env->NewStringUTF("Failed to initialize VrApi");
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "VrApiSuccess", "VrApi initialized successfully");
    }

    ovrModeParms modeParms = vrapi_DefaultModeParms(&java);
    modeParms.Display = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(display);
    modeParms.WindowSurface = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(window);
    modeParms.ShareContext = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(context);
    ovrMobile* mobile = vrapi_EnterVrMode(&modeParms);

    if (!mobile) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "VRMode", "Failed to enter VR mode");
        vrapi_Shutdown();
        ANativeWindow_release(window);
        eglDestroyContext(display, context);
        eglTerminate(display);
        return env->NewStringUTF("Failed to enter VR mode");
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "VRModeSuccess", "Successfully entered VR mode");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        const double predictedDisplayTime = vrapi_GetPredictedDisplayTime(mobile, 0);
        const ovrTracking2 tracking = vrapi_GetPredictedTracking2(mobile, predictedDisplayTime);

        // 检查tracking status
        if (tracking.Status & VRAPI_TRACKING_STATUS_POSITION_VALID) {
            float accX = tracking.HeadPose.LinearAcceleration.x;
            float accY = tracking.HeadPose.LinearAcceleration.y;
            float accZ = tracking.HeadPose.LinearAcceleration.z;

            char info[256];
            snprintf(info, sizeof(info), "Accelerometer Data - X: %f, Y: %f, Z: %f", accX, accY, accZ);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "AccelerometerInfo", "%s", info);
        } else {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "TrackingStatus", "Tracking status invalid: %d", tracking.Status);
        }

        usleep(33333); 
    }

    vrapi_LeaveVrMode(mobile);
    vrapi_Shutdown();
    ANativeWindow_release(window);
    eglDestroyContext(display, context);
    eglTerminate(display);

    return env->NewStringUTF("Data collection finished.");
}

I'm expecting to get the accelerometer's data to be not 0, and reflect the true value when I'm running this app. As I adding some debugger in my code, I found that the tracking.status is invalid and return 0, I think this is why it won't return the true value. I'm looking some methods to get it valid.
